# Pandas: How to create a new column where values based on conditions column-wise

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a column in my df. There are only three distinct values: Apple, banana and kiwi

```py
Category 
Apple 
Apple 
Apple 
Banana
Kiwi 
Banana
Banana
Banana
```

And I would like to insert a new column of their corresponding color

```
Category Color
Apple Red
Banana yellow
Kiwi green
```

How can i create such a column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df['Color'] = ['Red', 'yellow', 'green']
```

To accommodate the edit:

```
df['Color'] = df['Category'].map({'Apple': 'Red', 'Banana': 'yellow', 'Kiwi': 'green'})
```

```
    Category    Color
0   Apple   Red
1   Apple   Red
2   Apple   Red
3   Banana  yellow
4   Kiwi    green
5   Banana  yellow
6   Banana  yellow
7   Banana  yellow
```

Comment: There are 3 distinct values. And I would like to create the column based the anther column value.